# Excel-C#: How to read the formulas from a cell?

Tags: c#, excel

With this method I read the content of a cell:

```
Range range = (Range)sheet.Cells[i, j];
            if ((range == null) || (range.Value2 == null)) return "";
            return range.Value2.ToString();
```

But how can I read the formula from a cell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `.Formula` or `.FormulaR1C1` properties on the returned cell, eg:

```
return range.Formula
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer [return range.Formula] is incorrect! is m

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).